# .Net Core 1.1 why Async Task gettting slower and slower then multiple requests happen

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I run some test using .Net Core 1.1 using below code.

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    return await Task.Run(() => Ok());
}
```

When i use AB (apache benchmark) tool to run test, for 1 request i get result in 
107.000 time per request.

But when i run using 2 request with 2 concurrent, i get the result in 
433.162 time per request.

Seem like the async is not helping much in concurrent processing. The more request it get, the more time it spend to process per request. I'm expecting it to be almost similar to 1 request event when multiple request is feeding in.

Not sure if i'm writing my code right or I understand wrongly about async?

Comment: how about your server configuration (CPU cores, RAM )?